# can not persist the new object between requests - RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, omniauth

In my application, I have a twitter and facebook login, however I need to prompt a password and email after they first register with twitter or facebook. I am using omniauth gems and my controller/user model looks like this:

```
    //socials_controller.rb
    def create
        #render text: request.env['omniauth.auth'].to_yaml and return
        @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
        if(@user.email == nil)
          redirect_to patient_login_entry_url(@user)
        elsif @user.confirmed
          log_in @user
          redirect_to @user
        else
          flash[:danger]  = "Bir hata olustu."
          redirect_to root_url
        end
      end

 def login_entry
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update_social
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
    if @patient.update_attributes(user_params)
      SendVerificationEmailJob.perform_later @patient
      flash[:success]  = "Aktivasyon için #{@patient.email} adresinizi kontrol ediniz."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:danger]  = "Bilgilerinizi kontrol edip tekrar deneyiniz."
      redirect_to patient_login_entry_url(@patient)
    end
  end
```

and my from_omniauth method is:

```
//user.rb
has_secure_password
class << self
    def from_omniauth(auth_hash)
      if exists?(uid: auth_hash['uid'])
        user = find_by(uid: auth_hash['uid'])
      else
        user = find_or_create_by(uid: auth_hash['uid'], provider: auth_hash['provider'], type: 'Patient')
        user.location = get_social_location_for user.provider, auth_hash['info']['location']
        if auth_hash.provider == 'facebook'
          user.avatar = User.process_uri(auth_hash['info']['image'])
          user.name = auth_hash['extra']['raw_info']['first_name']
          user.surname = auth_hash['extra']['raw_info']['last_name']
          user.email = auth_hash['extra']['raw_info']['email']
          user.gender = auth_hash['extra']['raw_info']['gender']
        elsif auth_hash.provider == 'twitter'
          user.avatar = auth_hash['info']['image']
          user.name = auth_hash['info']['name']
        end
        user.url = get_social_url_for user.provider, auth_hash['info']['urls']
        user.save!
      end
      user
    end
```

At the `login_entry` page, I simply prompt the email and password, and POSTing them to the `update_social` method.

However, as expected, my app throws the error "Password can't be blank", because has_secure_password validates its presence by default. So, I need to persist it between the requests since I can not save it without a password. How can I achieve this?

I tried to store the created object in session by using `to_json` method, and turning it into a hash between requests, however this time the profile picture I got from twitter/facebook did not persist (I'm using AWS S3 + Paperclip, the URL persists but there is no such image when I check it from the S3 console) so I think that solution was not good.

Comment: You can save it and bypass the valdiations with `user.save!(validate: false)`

Comment: You can store the password in the session between the two requests.